# VueJS doesn't show data on a component but shows on console

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have two pages - Books and Book. I am trying to show some data on my Book page after clicking the single item from the Books page.

I have managed to fetch the JSON file which lists all the items on the Books page as well as a link to navigate to the Book page by id.

The problem I am facing is I can't fetch the data which is returned by JSON on the Book page. The data is hidden but console.log(response.data) shows response data on console without a problem.

Here is the route-link from the Books page which navigates a single Book:

```
<router-link :to="'/books/' + book.id"> Link </router-link>
```

And here is my Book component script

```
<script>
import LibraryDataService from "../services/LibraryDataService";

export default {
  name: "Book",
  data() {
    return {
      book: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getBook(id) {
      LibraryDataService.get(id)
        .then((response) => {
          this.book = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getBook(this.$route.params.id);
  },
};
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue by modifiying response.data on the getBook method as this.book = response.data[0];

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait for response:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getBook(this.$route.params.id);
},
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the tip, but it results to  parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'.

Comment: @gxvr hey mate, did you put async also?

Comment: Not really, anyways I have been able to solve the issue by adding [0] on my response data

Comment: ok nice, but if you need to use await you must set async in front of the func call, cheers :)

Comment: Oh nice, I will do so